# Formatação de campo texto para PIS/PASEP

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Na verdade não se trata de uma pergunta e sim de uma ajuda. Estive pesquisando máscara de PIS/PASEP e não encontrei então foi o jeito implementar.

Vou colocar a resposta abaixo.

Abraços.

Comment: Como assim Cesar?

Comment: Adicionei o código javascript abaixo R.Santos.

Comment: Qual é o formato do pis/pased? poderia colocar isso na pergunta.

Comment: O formato é 000.00000.00.0 com 14 posições formatado e 11 sem formatação. abraço.

Answer (score 8):

Segue abaixo funções necessárias.

**//Função principal**

```
function mascara(o, f) {
   v_obj = o
   v_fun = f
   setTimeout("execmascara()", 1)
}
```

**//Função de execução de qualquer máscara.**

```
function execmascara() {
   v_obj.value = v_fun(v_obj.value)
}
```

**//Função de formatação do PisPasep**
*// return '000.00000.00.0'*

```
function pispasep(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, "")                                      //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v = v.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2")                        //Coloca ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
    v = v.replace(/^(\d{3})\.(\d{5})(\d)/, "$1.$2.$3")            //Coloca ponto entre o quinto e o sexto dígitos
    v = v.replace(/(\d{3})\.(\d{5})\.(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1.$2.$3.$4") //Coloca ponto entre o décimo e o décimo primeiro dígitos
    return v
}
```

**//Função para validação do número do PisPasep**

function validarPIS(pis) {

```
var multiplicadorBase = "3298765432";
var total = 0;
var resto = 0;
var multiplicando = 0;
var multiplicador = 0;
var digito = 99;

// Retira a mascara
var numeroPIS = pis.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
if (numeroPIS.length !== 11 ||
    numeroPIS === "00000000000" ||
    numeroPIS === "11111111111" ||
    numeroPIS === "22222222222" ||
    numeroPIS === "33333333333" ||
    numeroPIS === "44444444444" ||
    numeroPIS === "55555555555" ||
    numeroPIS === "66666666666" ||
    numeroPIS === "77777777777" ||
    numeroPIS === "88888888888" ||
    numeroPIS === "99999999999") {
    return false;
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        multiplicando = parseInt(numeroPIS.substring(i, i + 1));
        multiplicador = parseInt(multiplicadorBase.substring(i, i + 1));
        total += multiplicando * multiplicador;
    }
    resto = 11 - total % 11;
    resto = resto === 10 || resto === 11 ? 0 : resto;
    digito = parseInt("" + numeroPIS.charAt(10));
    return resto === digito;
}
```

}
**Exemplo:** Adicione um input e coloque a chamada ao método mascara.

```
Pis/Pasep: "<"input type="text" id="pis" onkeyup="mascara(this, pispasep);" maxlength="14" onblur="if(validarPIS(this.value)){}else{alert('Número do PisPasep Inválido!');}"/>
```

**Importante:**  Não esquecer do *maxlength="14"*

**Validação:**  No exemplo que coloquei a validação é feita no onblur do input mostrando a mensagem *Número do PisPasep Inválido!*

Abraços!

César Rabelo!

Comment: mas e se é valido ou não?

Comment: Vou adicionar a parte da validação.

Comment: Leo Caracciolo acabei de adicionar a validação. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Muito bom, Cesar Rabelo L JR, com certeza vai ajudar muito!!!

Comment: Faz um código executável aqui! Acho que vai ficar legal. +1 acho que vai ser de grande ajuda pro pessoal.